# Queries within queries counting rows to make a score based on categories chosen

Tags: sql, mysql

Is there a way this hand coded query could become dynamic?

```
SELECT master.id,
(select count(0) as score1 from scores where scores.id = master.id AND scores.category = '1'),
(select count(0) as score2 from scores where scores.id = master.id AND scores.category = '2'),
(select count(0) as score3 from scores where scores.id = master.id AND scores.category = '3'),
( repeat for as many categories chosen by the current user )
score1+score2+score3 AS score FROM master ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 1
```

I know this syntax is incorrect.

The effect I want is depending on a users chosen categories, I want to find a record.  Each record is scored in another table.

I want to be able to repeat the queries in brackets as many times as there are categories found in another database based on another id:

```
anotherid,category
1,1
1,2
1,3
2,2
2,3
3,1
3,2
3,3
```

So if I passed '1' to the query above I'd like it to repeat the query in brackets for the result categories 1,2 and 3 (so three queries resulting in three scores adding up to an overall total).

I have tried to ask this question before, but I think I over complicated things!

**UPDATE:**

I have just made this query - and I think it works.  Anyone see any obvious mistakes?

```
SELECT
users.id,
users.url,
(
SELECT SUM(scoretot.scr) FROM scoretot WHERE scoretot.id = users.id AND scoretot.category 
IN (
SELECT category FROM getprefs WHERE member = '2'
)
) AS score
FROM users
ORDER BY score DESC limit 1
```

The value 2 will be dynamically created in the query in Perl (it will be the ID of the current user).

I have two VIEWS

```
create view getprefs select `prefs`.`category` AS `category`,`prefs`.`member` AS `member` from `prefs`

create view scoretot select count(`scores`.`ref`) AS `scr`,`scores`.`id` AS `id`,`scores`.`category` AS `category` from `scores` group by `scores`.`category`
```

And three tables:

table users:

```
id,url
1,www.test.com
2,www.test2.com
3,www.test3.com
```

table scores:

```
id,category
1,1
1,1
1,2
1,2
1,3
1,3
1,3
2,2
3,1
3,3
3,3
3,3
3,2
```

table prefs

```
member,category
1,1
1,2
1,3
2,1
3,1
3,3
```

"think" that's it....

Comment: It would be easier to make a query that returns the values you want if you return each value as a separate row instead of a column. Have you considered this as an option?

Comment: @Chris, your example is such difficult to read. Could you please reformat it using linebreaks and capitalize the SQL keywords?

Comment: Hi, I have changed the above "idea" code as requested.  Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, basically you want to code a pivot table. 
First, an easier way to do it, with less typing and less overhead would be:

```
SELECT    master.id
,         SUM(IF(s.category='1',1,0))   cat1
,         SUM(IF(s.category='2',1,0))   cat2
,         SUM(1)                        total
FROM      master m
LEFT JOIN scores s
ON        m.id = s.id
GROUP BY  master.id
```

(here's an exaplanation and background: http://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2005/10/creating-crosstabs-in-mysql.html)

The trick is of course to generate the columns dynamically. Turns out, you can do this with a stored procedure. Here's an example of how you can do that:
http://www.futhark.ch/mysql/106.html

If you are using MySQL proxy, you can also take a look at http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/ProxyCookbook

Comment: That's pretty close, thanks!  What I may do is create my own sql statement based on the categories chosen with Perl first.  This combined with a universal VIEW and I'm there! One day I think I could get my head around one single SQL statement, but it's not imperative!

Comment: There is a Perl solution already:

http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/wizard/index.html

Comment: After visiting your links and reading everything, this is exactly what I need.  Thank you so much!  Just got to put it into action... :(

Answer (score 0):

for better readability I would recommend that you create separate `views` for your subqueries.

```
CREATE VIEW v_scores_category1 AS 
    SELECT count(0) AS score1
    FROM scores where scores.id = mASter.id AND scores.category = '1'

CREATE VIEW v_scores_category2 AS
    SELECT count(0) AS score2
    FROM scores where scores.id = id AND scores.category = '2'
```

and then ...

```
SELECT mASter.id,
(SELECT score1 FROM v_scores_category1),
(SELECT score2 FROM v_scores_category2),
score1+score2 AS score FROM mASter ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 1
```

BTW: I know this syntax is incorrect ;) ...

Comment: Thinking about it, I could have ONE view for all such as
CREATE VIEW getscores SELECT count(id) as scr,category FROM scores GROUP BY category (I think) then SELECT scr FROM getscores WHERE category = [whatever]